How do I extract the values stored in an object returned from a runJavaScriptReturningResult function call?
I'm working on a flutter app which has a webview where I've called a runJavaScriptReturningResult function to return the results of a simple query which I've show below.
Future<void> _injectJavascript(BuildContext context) async {
    final ret = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
        'document.getElementsByClassName("status-col")[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML + ": " + document.getElementsByClassName("status-col")[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].title');
    FFAppState().paymenturlappstate = ret.toString();
    return;
}

The problem is that this returns an object, which I don't know how to parse. It isn't indexable, and converting to string as shown above only tells me the class of the object. I haven't found anything similar anywhere else, and the documentation hasn't given me anything to go on. Is there any way for me to get the string this object returns?

Your function _injectJavascript does not seem to return anything. Can you try changing the return statement to return ret and updating the function signature from Future<void> to the correct type.

you can use Dart's type casting to extract the string value from this object
Future<void> _injectJavascript(BuildContext context) async {
  final result = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
      'document.getElementsByClassName("status-col")[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML + ": " + document.getElementsByClassName("status-col")[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].title');

  if (result != null && result is String) {
    FFAppState().paymenturlappstate = result;
  } else {
  }
  return;
}

